# Why apple push notification service sometimes gives me error 500?

Tags: node.js, apple-push-notifications

I have a node.js project that i use for the backend of an app, I have to send push notifications to android and ios, the thing is, the APNS sometimes gives me an error 500 trying to send the notification.

Here's the usual response:

```
{ sent: [],
failed: [ { device: '<device_id>',
status: '500',
response: { reason: 'InternalServerError' } } ]
```

I read that if you send to much at a time the APNS can refuse the connection, the thing is that i normally don't send that much, like at most 1 notifications per second.

I use node-apn, heres the code that sends the notification.

```
function sendIosNotification(deviceTokens,body,data,musico) {
  var notification = new apn.Notification();
  if (musico) {
    notification.topic = "<name_goes_here>.musico";
  } else {
    notification.topic = "<name_goes_here>.cliente";
  }
  notification.alert = body;
  notification.badge = 1;
  notification.sound = "dong.aiff";
  notification.payload = data;
  apnProvider.send(notification, deviceTokens)
  .then( (response) => {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.failed);
  });
}
```

It works, I have it mounted in a test server, but when I, for example, leave it overnight, the next day it only gives me errors 500. It usually fixes itself by restarting the node server, but this can't happen in production. is there something i can do to fix this?, is it an APNS problem or something that i'm doing?.

EDIT: I'm using this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/apn

Comment: Have same problem

Comment: Maybe you've fixed it somehow?

Comment: It keeps happening, I can't seem to find what causes it. Because that project kinda died I never fixed it, I'll check it out again later and see what I can find, If you find it out i would be forever grateful.

Comment: Also, I'm just realising i didn't said what NPM package im using.

I using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/apn , Are you using the same package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the primary author of [Pushy](https://github.com/relayrides/pushy), a push notification library for Java. I can't speak with authority about the specifics of the library you're using, but can comment with confidence on APNs in general.

This sounds like an upstream bug; there are no circumstances where the APNs server should be sending an `InternalServerError` instead of something more concrete ("expired authentication token" or "too many messages," for example); `InternalServerError` definitely indicates something is going wrong on Apple's side. My strong recommendation would be to [file a bug report with Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com/); I don't think this is something that can be solved on your end or by the `apn` package's author.

Comment: Seems like it, this was some time ago and since then i've discontinued that project. But Right now I'm using this code in an ongoing project, I'll see if this happens again and gather data to notify apple. Thanks for the suggestion :)